# Music player is messed up with Video player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple music player written in html5/javascript which can only play one loop, with one play/pause button.
        [LINK 1](http://jsfiddle.net/nojava/sda6zocs/)
I’m trying built a new player which can play more than one song with arrow function. After days of researching, I found a reference which I like very much. I combined the code from the reference into my first script and created this [LINK 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nojava/wbdyb4br/) which doesn’t work at all.

```
var audio = new Audio(),
i = 0;
var playlist = new Array('http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/horse.mp3','http://sifidesign.com/audio/explosion.mp3');

Audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
i = ++i < playlist.length ? i : 0;
console.log(i)
Audio.src = playlist[i];
Audio.play();
}, true);

Audio.volume = 0.5;
Audio.loop = false;
Audio.src = playlist[0];

function aud_play_pause() {
if (Audio.paused) {
Audio.play(); 
} 
else {
Audio.pause();
}
}
```

I have a very little knowledge of coding. All I want is an one-button-play/pause player which can play more than one song. Please help :)

Comment: Please provide more information. What error are you getting, what part do you think is not working etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see the difference between `audio` and `Audio`.

What you need is a created instance (`audio`, which you named lowercase), but you trying to reach by calling `Audio` instead. Since variable names in javascript are case-sensative your code won't work as expected.

Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/nfpa7j5n/

Comment: you use the same variable `i` to control two different counters